# Cell self-reference in Excel

Tags: excel, variables

Is there a way to self-reference the cell inside an expression?

For example:
if I want A2 cell to have +1 value in respect of the cell above I write:

```
=A1+1
```

If I cut and paste this expression in another cell, it still references to A1.
How to replace that `=A1+1` with something like:

```
=cell.value(this.X,(this.Y-1))+1
```

**UPDATE**

Just another use case: create a numbered list (yes, I know excel lines are already numbered, but what about printing?).

Until now I put 1 in A1, `=A1+1` in A2 and then dragged A2 lower right corner down to the desired line.
In this way if I delete a row, the following ones become of undefined value.

By putting `=OFFSET(A2;-1;0)+1` in A2 and dragging, I can then delete intermediate lines without breaking the sequence.

I guess there are zillions of better/smarter/faster ways of doing this.

Comment: Copy/paste instead of cutting? You can use `OFFSET` but you shouldn't (it's a volatile function). You can use `INDEX` as well. But this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: user3598756 gave the exact answer. That was the exact information I was looking for. I didn't know the existence of the OFFSET() function until now. Still can't understand the downvoting to my question. Was it so stupid? Was it ridicolous? Was it rude or disrespectful? For how bad it was, it made me learn something new.

Comment: `OFFSET` is volatile and should be use sparingly. Note, not my downvote.

Comment: @BigBen didn't mean it was you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Offset()`

so the cell formula would be:

```
=OFFSET(A1;-1;0)+1
```

Comment: For italian speaking people: OFFSET() in italian Excel version is SCARTO()

Comment: This is a truly smart suggestion. Nonetheless, the expression still contains an absolute refence to a cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy&paste the actual contents while editing the cell, paste will then put the exact same text into any other cell you select. If you make sure you are not editing the cell, highlight it, copy and then paste into another cell, Excel will automatically update the column and row.

Highlight the cell when not in edit mode, paste into the one below, it will automatically update the row number, =A1+1 will become =A2+1. If you paste it into the cell to the right, it will update the column letter, =A1+1 will become B1+1.

So, for example, if you have the number 9 in cell A1, then enter =A1+1 in cell A2 it will show a value of 10, if you then copy cell A2 (the cell, not the contents) to cell A3, that cell will display the value 11, and contain =A2+1.

If you want to do a long range of cells that add 1 to the previous cell, taking the previous example, highlight cells A2 and A3 then click and hold on the little square at the bottom right of the selection, and drag it as far down column A as you want.